# boto and attaching a ebs to ec2 ...now what?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I have used the below to attach a volume to ec2 using boto.  I am using ubuntu 12.04.

```
region_id=boto.ec2.get_region(region,aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    conn = ec2.connection.EC2Connection(region=region_id,aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    vol = conn.create_volume(gigs,placement)
    vol.attach(intsance_id, '/dev/sdh')
```

I am no expert on drives.  I want to use it for mongo.  I assume I have to log into the instance and prep the EBS.  My question is how?  I tried the below.

```
grep -q xfs /proc/filesystems || sudo modprobe xfs
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
/dev/sdh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

On the recent Ubuntu machines, the devices get mapped to `/dev/xvdX`. In your case, this should be `/dev/xvdh`. Try creating the filesystem with this device id and mount it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it didn't get attached as /dev/sdh/.  Try doing:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

to find the correct device name.

Answer (score 0):

First the way that you have attached it ads and extra unnecessary step.  So attach it as /dev/sdh1 instead and the following will work.  Otherwise you need to also create a partition on the disk using fdisk.

Once your instance has started you need to create a file system on the device, and then mount it.

That will look something like this

To create an xfs file system

```
mkfs.xfs -f /dev/xvdh1
```

To mount(attach the new file system to a directory):

```
mkdir /mnt/more_storage
mount -t xfs /dev/xvdh1 /mnt/more_storage
```

Finally if you want to see this the next time you reboot you need to add something like the following to your /etc/fstab

```
/dev/xvdh1    /mnt/more_storage xfs     defaults,noatime  0   0
```

This example uses xfs, you can choose ext3/ext4 or whichever you perfer.

The directory /mnt/more_storage can be literally any empty directory on the system.  The directory needs to exist before you run the mount command and must be empty.  It could just as easily be /var/mongo/data.

Though, as you said this was for mongo, I am going to make a further suggestion.  Divide up the space you require by at least 5 but maybe 8 or 10.  So if you need 100GB then create 5 EBS volumes of 20GB each or 10 of 10GB each.  Then attach them as you did originally, not specifying the partition number or /dev/sdh.  So for example I am going to stick with 5 to save typing, though some where around 8 will give you optimal throughput.  So now you have attached /dev/sdh, /dev/sdi, /dev/sdj, /dev/sdk, and /dev/sdl.

Now you need an extra step from the above to create a striped raid across those EBS volumes

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-device=5 /dev/xvdh /dev/xvdi /dev/xvdj /dev/xvdk /dev/xvdl
```

This will create a new device located at /dev/md0.  Now replace /dev/xvdh1 with /dev/md0 in the above examples and create the file system and mount it.

```
mount -t xfs /dev/md0 /mnt/more_storage
/dev/md0    /mnt/more_storage xfs     defaults,noatime  0   0
```

You also want this to work after reboot so you need the following commands:

```
echo "DEVICE /dev/xvdh /dev/xvdi /dev/xvdj /dev/xvdk /dev/xvdl" >> /etc/mdadm.conf
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
echo "/dev/md0    /mnt/more_storage xfs     defaults,noatime  0   0" >> /etc/fstab
```